# 301 Redirect issue when term in new and old URL

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

We are trying to create a set of 301 redirects where the exact string from the old URL is also present in the same position in the new URL. See the example below:

**Old URL**

```
http://www.domain.com/foobar
```

**New URL**

```
http://www.domain.com/foobar/i55
```

We've tried a standard 301 redirect like this:

```
Redirect 301 /foobar$ http://www.domain.com/foobar/i55
```

This doesn't work and causes a 404:

```
File does not exist: /home/domain/public_html/foobar
```

Should we be looking at rewrite rules instead or can this be fixed by just adjusting the 301 rule?

Thanks.

Comment: When you enter `http://www.domain.com/foobar/i55` in browser does it open a valid page?

Comment: yes it does - that is the valid new URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the RedirectMatch in mod_alias i.e:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /foobar$ http://www.domain.com/foobar/i55
```

EDITED BASED COMMENT

Comment: i don't need the variable from the right so not sure that is necessary. Either way that creates a redirect loop in Chrome

Comment: soory - only dawned on me that the domains were the same. Will edit